# How to get the nested array value?

Tags: tcl

I have a nested array as below:

```
array set arrayA {0 {1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d}}
```

If I want to update the arrayA like this:

```
set arrayA(0)(1) "update"
```

It can't get {0 {1 update 2 b...}}, how to get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tcl arrays can't be nested that way, but your code is still valid. In `arrayA`, the value of element 0 is a `dict`, so you can get and set members in it with `dict` operations:

```
% dict get $arrayA(0) 1
a
% dict set arrayA(0) 1 update
1 update 2 b 3 c 4 d
```

Another alternative is to use composite names for the array members:

```
array set arrayA {0.1 a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.4 d 1.1 aa 1.2 ab}
```

and access them with `arrayA(0.1)`, `arrayA(0.$foo)` etc. Which separator character to use is mostly a question of preference, the only rule is that the name must be a proper list. You don't even really need a separator, as long as you always keep the element name in a variable:

```
% array set arrayA {{0 1} a {0 2} b}
% set idx {0 1}
0 1
% set arrayA($idx)
a
```

Documentation:

[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm)

Comment: Got it, Thanks very much!

Comment: @Jimmy: np, elaborated a little bit when I found a keyboard.

Comment: It used to be possible to nest arrays a long time ago through a quirk of upvar, but there was no convenient syntax at all and it was really a bug. You haven't been able to nest them since at least 8.4; the upvar code now only ever makes variables with the same properties as the variables it links to.